# i is not defined using map() with ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to create a li in react but failed. Error is near the map(), I got error of i is not defined, why?

```
const TodoItems = React.creatClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      items : [
        {id:1,name:"Gym"},
        {id:2,name:"Jump"},
        {id:3,name:"Racing"}
      ] 
    }
  },
  renderItem(){
    return(
      <ul>
      this.state.items.map(item,i => 
        <li key={i}>item.name</li>
      )
      </ul>
    ) 
  },
  render(){
    return (
      <renderItem />
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't `React.creatClass` be `React.createClass`? I'd expect you to be getting an error about that well before the `map` call.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://jsfiddle.net/w1ngbrva/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have multiple arguments for an arrow function, you need to put `()` around them. So:

```
this.state.items.map((item,i) => 
// ------------------^------^
    <li key={i}>item.name</li>
)
```

Your original code calls `map` with `item` as its first argument, and an arrow function taking a single argument (`i`) as its second argument.

You also need to put `item.name` in `{}` *and* put the call to `map` in `{}`:

```
renderItem(){
  return(
    <ul>
    {this.state.items.map((item,i) => 
      <li key={i}>{item.name}</li>
    )}
    </ul>
  )
```

Then it works:

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const TodoItems = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      items : [
        {id:1,name:"Gym"},
        {id:2,name:"Jump"},
        {id:3,name:"Racing"}
      ] 
    }
  },
  renderItem(){
    return(
      <ul>
      {this.state.items.map((item,i) => 
        <li key={i}>{item.name}</li>
      )}
      </ul>
    ) 
  },
  render(){
    return this.renderItem();
  }
});
    
render(<TodoItems /> , document.getElementById('items'));
```

```html
<div id="items"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

That became clear to me when I used [Babel's REPL to compile the JSX](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&code=const%20%7B%20Component%20%7D%20%3D%20React%3B%0Aconst%20%7B%20render%20%7D%20%3D%20ReactDOM%3B%0A%0Aconst%20TodoItems%20%3D%20React.createClass(%7B%0A%20%20getInitialState()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20items%20%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bid%3A1%2Cname%3A%22Gym%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bid%3A2%2Cname%3A%22Jump%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bid%3A3%2Cname%3A%22Racing%22%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20renderItem()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.state.items.map((item%2Ci)%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20key%3D%7Bi%7D%3Eitem.name%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20render()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.renderItem()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0Arender(%3CTodoItems%20%2F%3E%20%2C%20document.getElementById('items'))%3B%0Aconsole.log(%22Got%20here%22)%3B) and realized I was seeing `"this.state.map((item,i) =>"` as a *string*.

Comment: Still the same error, I wrap those 2 arg in `()` before.

Comment: how about I push a repo and u experiment it yourself? It still gave me the error.

Comment: @MariaJane: The content of questions must be here on-site. Surely you're at least 80% to an [mcve] already?

Comment: @MariaJane: Again: The content of the question must be here, on-site, not elsewhere. But I was able to get it working in a snippet, see above.

Comment: @MariaJane: I've never tried to use ReactJS in jsFiddle.

Comment: somehow I couldn't see anything rendered in my own environment https://github.com/eldyvoon/react-todo

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
renderItem(){
        return(
          <ul>
          {this.state.items.map((item,i) => {
            return(
             <li key={i}>item.name</li>);
          })}
          </ul>
        )
```

Comment: yeah Im sure about that.

Comment: I got this erorr now `App.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: _react2.default.creatClass is not a function`

Comment: Nice one, but please be sure to always include **explanation** in answers. Say specifically *what* you changed (it's easy to miss small changes like the `{}` you added), and *why* (for instance, why does Maria need `()` on the arrow function).

Comment: @AlirezaValizade do you mind take a look what's wrong here? I build my starter using create-react-app